# How do I resolve if the texture does not load on the Ursina Engine? (load_texture does not work)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create The minecraft python of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHSRaVeQxIk)
But, when i tried to add a texture, the texture does not load

[image]

If someone can help me

```
from ursina import *

def update():
if held_keys['a']:
    sans.x -= 6 * time.dt
if held_keys['d']:
    sans.x -= -6 * time.dt
  
app = Ursina() 

square = Entity(model = 'quad', color = color.red) 

sans = Entity(model = 'quad', texture = ('assets/sans.png')) 

app.run()
```

Comment: Read the [entity basics](https://www.ursinaengine.org/entity_basics.html) before asking such a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sans_texture = load_texture('assets/sans.png')
sans = Entity(model = 'quad', color = color.red, texture = sans_texture)
```

Comment: I've tried, and it didn't work, but thanks for the try

Answer (score 0):

check the second last line, there'll be no braces:

```
sans = Entity(model = 'quad', texture = 'assets/sans.png')
```

moreover try removing this line, else it'll create an additional square behind it (or maybe above it, which is why you aren't able to see it):

```
square = Entity(model = 'quad', color = color.red)
```

so here's your code:

```
from ursina import *

def update():
if held_keys['a']:
    sans.x -= 6 * time.dt
if held_keys['d']:
    sans.x -= -6 * time.dt


app = Ursina()

sans = Entity(model='quad', texture='assets/sans.png')


app.run()
```

also make sure that the image is actually png, and not just a jpg that was renamed, it may also cause an issue.

know i am late, but just got stuck on the same problem, and solved it. good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

the same problem happened to me. This problem happens from time to time. What image do you give to the system to have very large dimensions? I solved my problem by using special sites for resizing the image. Try to change the dimensions of your image from 1760 *1760 should not be more